# Compare dates in "Y F jS, g:i a" format, ex: "2018 September 3rd, 9:30 am"

Tags: php, date, compare

Trying to do a simple date comparison. Both dates are in the format of "Y F jS, g:i a". e.g. 2018 September 3rd, 9:30 am.

```
$today = date('Y F jS, g:i a');
$expire = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenance/end_time.php');

if($today>$expire){
  unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenance/end_time.php');
}
```

The code  I have doesn't work correctly. I also tried strototime() but that was also unsuccessful.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php

Comment: echo $today; results in 2018 September 3rd, 9:37 am

echo $expire; results in 2018 August 31st, 4:52 pm

Comment: best use [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) with [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
$today_dt = new DateTime($today);
$expire_dt = new DateTime($expire);

if ($today_dt > $expire_dt) 
 { /* Do something */ }
```

**Update:**  It might possible that the date string is not supported by DateTime parser so you can initialize your dates like this.

```
$today_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F jS, g:i a', $today);
$expire_dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y F jS, g:i a', $expire);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018 September 3rd, 9:42 am) at position 15 (3): Unexpected character' in C:\PatentorderDEV\Include\user_access.php on line 9

Line 9 is   $today_dt = new DateTime($today);

Comment: I have Updated my answer

Comment: I glad that I could help you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime`

```
$today = time();
$expire = strtotime(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenance/end_time.php'));

if($today>$expire){
  //code
}
```

OR

```
$today = date('Y F jS, g:i a');
$expire = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenance/end_time.php');

if(strtotime($today) > strtotime($expire)){
  unlink(dirname(__FILE__).'/maintenance/end_time.php');
}
```

Comment: `time()` would be easier for the first line, wouln't it?

Comment: This code was valid but did not work successfully. Not sure why